# How to crawl images in Nutch?

Tags: solr, nutch

How to crawl images in Nutch? Or, is there any other open search engine which is producing the results with images?

Answer (score 0):

change your `regex-urlfilter.txt` in `conf`

> -.(ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|exe|EXE|js|JS|gif|GIF|png|PNG||jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|mpg|MPG|mov|MOV)$

Delete `jpeg`, `jpg`, `gif` or `type` picture that you want to *grep*.

And then change `suffix-urlfilter.txt` in `conf`

add `#` to `jpeg`, `gif` or `png`

That worked for me!